# Fuzzing closed application

Tags: c, fuzzing

I want to get from you some advice about fuzzing.

I am checking a huge C application (not open source) which is also an HTTP server.

My purpose is to fuzz the HTTP server via the requests being sent to the server for finding memory corruptions.

There are various tools for fuzzing: AFLNET, AFL (libdesock does not work well), honggfuzz and so on.

What are some examples of what would it look like to fuzz my application using an open-source tool like those that I have listed?